# Rails Rolify how to test for multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I would like to test for multiple roles using rolify.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
<% if current_user.has_role? [:technician, :admin] %>
```

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

I'm trying to test for :technician or :admin - this works but seems like there should be a shorter way:

```
if current_user.has_role? :technician or current_user.has_role? :admin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Rolify docs](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Usage#multiple-role-checking):

Multiple role checking
Check if the user has ALL specified roles

```
  user = User.find(1)
  user.add_role :admin # sets a global role
  user.add_role :moderator, Forum.first # sets a role scoped to a resource instance
  user.add_role :visitor, Forum # sets a role scoped to a resource class
  user.has_all_roles? :admin, { :name => :moderator, :resource => Forum.first }, { :name => :visitor, :resource => Forum }
  => true
  user.has_all_roles? :admin, { :name => :moderator, :resource => Forum.last }
  => false
  user.has_all_roles? :god, { :name => :visitor, :resource => Forum }
  => false
```

Check if the user has ANY of the specified role(s)

```
  user = User.find(1)
  user.add_role :admin # sets a global role
  user.add_role :moderator, Forum.first # sets a role scoped to a resource
  user.add_role :visitor, Forum # set a role scoped to a resource class
  user.has_any_role? :admin, { :name => :moderator, :resource => Forum.first }, { :name => :visitor, :resource => Forum }
  => true
  user.has_any_role? :admin, { :name => :moderator, :resource => Forum.last }
  => true
  user.has_any_role? :god, { :name => :visitor, :resource => Forum }
  => true
```

So it looks like in your situation you want to use:

```
user.has_all_roles? :technician, {:name => :admin}
```

Comment: I'm trying to test for :technician or :admin  - this works but seems like there should be a shorter way: if current_user.has_role? :technician or current_user.has_role? :admin

Comment: Did you try that? A simple `or` statement is totally an option: `do_something if user.has_role?(:foo) || user.has_role?(:bar)`

Comment: This answer isn't working for me. Was in 3.x now in 5.x ... didn't work in either.. just get false everytime.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend you test something like `current_user.has_any_role? :technician, :admin`, it should return you the boolean you're expecting :)